# Sitecore User Group Denver - March 15, 2018

Tags: discussion, status-completed, community-event

Come join us in the Rocky Mountains!

Join us at Microsoft's Denver office at 7595 Technology Way to learn about Sitecore Forms and maximizing the editing experience for content authors. Toby Gutierrez, Sitecore MVP, will be dive into the brand new Sitecore 9 forms. Brandon Bruno, Sitecore MVP, will cover the principles behind good content author UX in Sitecore and some technical information on how to implement those principles.

- Date/Time (local/UTC): Thursday, March 15th 2018 at 5:30pm MST (11:30 UTC)
- Location:    7595 Technology Way #400, Denver, CO, 80237, us
- Event Details: https://www.meetup.com/Rocky-Mountain-Sitecore-User-Group-Denver/events/245906450/
- Contact: Toby Gutierrez @sitecoresandbox (Twitter or Slack)

We will have some snazzy swag, popular pizza, bewildering beers, and some pot belly laughs. Come share some best practices, and meet some new friends in the Sitecore community!

Comment: Add UTC time as well please.

Comment: Community Bulletin promotion begins in 4 days

Comment: Awesome. Thanks @MarkCassidy!